# Sharepoint Ms access 2010 database table guid

Tags: sharepoint, adodb, wss

I've uploaded a Access 2010 database to the sharepoint (2010) site. I want to connect to the Database through ADO (Excel Vba). Update/Delete/Add records to the table.

i'm able to connect to the database, as instructions provided in below site

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/54e32c6a-64bd-41f0-b24b-b6d6bf2aa9b6/trouble-inserting-into-sharepoint-access-db-with-adodb-connection?forum=accessdev

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String
dbURL = "http://www.mysharepointLink.com/Shared%20Documents/DataTest.accdb"

strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=" & dbURL & ";List=" & listGUID & ";"
```

I'm unable understand as how to find GUID for the TABLE in the database
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Guess a little too late to answer. Here's how you do it:

1. List settings from the SharePoint list
2. Advanced settings
3. In the address bar of your browser, you would see an ID, something like this: 15/advsetng.aspx?List=%7B9D9DF3A9%2D02FE%2D4096%2D9BBE%2DB7FBA5BD8C40%7D
4. Replace %7B with {
5. Replace %7D with }
6. Replace %2D with - (a hyphen)

That's your List ID.